# Scala immutable replacement to CopyOnWriteArrayList for fast iteration

Tags: scala, immutability

Javas CopyOnWriteArrayList advertises being very fast to iterate over rarely changing data structures in a thread safe manner. If I wanted to compare the performance with holding an AtomicReference to an Scala scala.collection.immutable data structure which one(s) should I benchmark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be `Vector`. It's an immutable, persistent (that's FP-speak for content sharing) `IndexedSeq` (amortized constant-time lookup by integer index).

Comment: `@volatle` reference to a `Vector` sounds like the answer then.

Comment: @simbo1905 volatile alone doesn't replace CopyOnWriteArrayList. The former is about memory visibility, the latter is about thread-safety and synchronization. If multiple threads write to a volatile variable, you still have race conditions.

Also, I don't fully understand how a Vector can replace a CopyOnWriteArrayList. In my opinion, this really depends on the use case. If you have multiple threads writing to the same collection, a normal variable doesn't guarantee that you have always the latest value when you read or write, considering that operations are not atomic and not synchronized.